# APPNAME would like to send you new issues and push notifications - what are 'new issues' and what triggers the alert to be shown?

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios7.1

When requesting permission to send push notifications the alert text used to read "APPNAME would like to send you push notifications".

recently it changed to read "APPNAME would like to send you new issues and push notifications"

1. What are 'new issues', and when are they sent?
2. What event triggers the app to ask the user to accept "New Issues"?

The problem I encounter is that the notification shows on app launch, without the app registering for push notifications, so an event besides registering the app for push notifications is triggering this alert.

(the app delays registering for push notifications until after we've told the user why we want to send them push notifications - eg http://techcrunch.com/2014/04/04/the-right-way-to-ask-users-for-ios-permissions/)

Comment: It sounds Newsstand-related. Can you produce a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks for that insight Jesse!! - Knowing that 'new issues' referred to new magazine issues in newsstand allowed me to track down the issue.

Comment: 1. New Issues refers to new content updates sent via NewsStand 2. Registering for UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability triggers the new issues alert